# Trying to do the Blazor/SignalR Chat App on YouTube with Blazor Server App instead of Web Assembly

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr

Here's the GitHub to author's repo:  https://github.com/modulardev2/ChatBlazorApp/tree/Video1

The author is using `Blazor Web Assembly` and I used `Blazor Server app`. When I click on chat tab, the browser tells my `Connection Id required`

Here's the razor component:

```
@page "/room1"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@implements IDisposable

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        User:
        <input @bind="userInput" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Message:
        <input @bind="messageInput" size="50" />
    </label>
</div>
<button @onclick="Send" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>

<hr>

<ul id="messagesList">
    @foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private HubConnection hubConnection;
    private List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    private string userInput;
    private string messageInput;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Add(encodedMsg);
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    Task Send() =>
        hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);

    public bool IsConnected =>
        hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ = hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

Chat Hub class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChatBlazorApp.Server.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Linq;
using ChatBlazorApp.Server.Hubs;

namespace ChatBlazorApp.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
            {
                opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                    new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseResponseCompression();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the MSDN tutorial for SignalR? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server

Answer (score 0):

Why are you building in `SignalR` for server side? The `default communication method` for `Blazor is SignalR`, so just build in your logic using `Dependency Injection` for your `message services`, and the `chat component` can then just `get and send user's messages` from these `services`.

Here is a rudimentary code sample: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/7lr7kd8s

Keep in mind, this is just a rough demonstration of how Dependency Injection can do what you want to achieve.

Move the code to a project, and run on two browser sessions (`use incognito/private browsing`) to mimic two different users.

### Code:

#### ChatClient.razor

```
@inject MessageService globalMessageService
@inject UserMessageService userMessageService

<h3>@(UserIdSet ? $"User: {UserID}" : "User: unknown")</h3>

@if (!UserIdSet)
{
    <input type="number" @bind-value="@UserID" placeholder="Insert your user ID" />
    <button @onclick="SetUserID">Set User ID</button>
}
else
{
    <div MessageContainer>
        @foreach (var message in userMessageService.UserMessages)
        {
            <div Message IsUser="@(message.CreatedBy == UserID)" NotMessage="@(message.RecipientIds == null)">
                <div Content>
                    @message.Message
                </div>
                @if (message.RecipientIds != null)
                {
                    <span Details>@message.CreatedBy @@ @message.Created.ToString("hh:mm:ss")</span>
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <input type="text" @bind-value="@Message" placeholder="add your message" />
    <button @onclick="SendMessage">Send Message</button>
}


@code {
    int UserID { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }

    bool UserIdSet { get; set; }

    async Task SetUserID()
    {
        userMessageService.SetUserId(UserID);

        globalMessageService.SendMessage(new ChatMessage(UserID, null, $"User {UserID} has joined the chat"));

        UserIdSet = true;

        await GetMessages();
    }

    void SendMessage()
    {
        var recipients = globalMessageService.Messages?.Select(m => m.CreatedBy).Distinct().ToList();

        globalMessageService.SendMessage(new ChatMessage(UserID, recipients, Message));
    }

    async Task GetMessages()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (UserID != default)
            {
                userMessageService.GetUserMessages();
                StateHasChanged();
            }

            await Task.Delay(300);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Startup.cs and required classes

```
namespace BlazorFiddleProject
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Builder;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<MessageService>();
            services.AddScoped<UserMessageService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }

    public class ChatMessage
    {
        public List<int> RecipientIds { get; private set; }
        public string Message { get; private set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; private set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; private set; }

        private ChatMessage() { }

        public ChatMessage(int createdBy, List<int> recipientIds, string message)
        {
            CreatedBy = createdBy;
            RecipientIds = recipientIds;
            Message = message;
            Created = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public class MessageService
    {
        public List<ChatMessage> Messages { get; set; } = new List<ChatMessage>();

        public void SendMessage(ChatMessage chatMessage)
        {
            //Add message to message store

            Messages.Add(chatMessage);
        }
    }

    public class UserMessageService // Inject as scoped service
    {
        MessageService MessageService { get; set; }

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        DateTime LastCheck = DateTime.MinValue;

        public List<ChatMessage> UserMessages { get; set; } = new List<ChatMessage>();

        public UserMessageService(MessageService messageService) => MessageService = messageService;

        public void SetUserId(int userId)
        {
            UserID = userId;
        }

        public void GetUserMessages()
        {
            if (UserID == 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(UserID), "A user ID has not been set for the user message service.");

            var messages = MessageService.Messages.Where(m =>
                (
                    m.RecipientIds?.Contains(UserID) == true
                    || m.RecipientIds == null
                    || m.CreatedBy == UserID
                )
                && m.Created > LastCheck)
                ?.ToList();

            if (messages?.Any() == true)
            {
                LastCheck = messages.Max(m => m.Created);

                UserMessages = UserMessages.Concat(messages).OrderBy(m => m.Created).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### SCSS

```
div[MessageContainer] {
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    width: 50vw;
    border-radius: .3em;

    div[Message] {

        &[NotMessage] {
            text-align: center;
        }

        &:not([NotMessage]) {
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 1em;
            background-color: #CCC;
            border-radius: .3em;
            margin-right: 5em;

            &[IsUser] {
                background-color: darkgreen;
                color: #FFF;
                margin-right: 1em;
                margin-left: 5em;
            }

            span[Details] {
                font-size: .7em;
                opacity: .7;
            }
        }
    }
}
```